# Google Chart: Pie Slice text weird position

Tags: charts, google-visualization, slice

When creating Pie Charts (using Google Chart) they would always output with very oddly positioned Slice Text/Annotations, and when a slice was very small the text would still be on the slice. See image below.
[image: Google Chart Pie Chart Output]
This would occur even using the copied Javascript code from the Google Charts examples. However, I would hide the chart div where the output needs to reside (using `display:none`) because I wanted to open the static chart in a new tab opposed to pasting it on the page.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the chart to generate correctly the DIV where your chart outputs to cannot be set to `display: none`. This seems to be a bug with Google Charts. I found a workaround if you want to hide the chart output DIV. You can set `visibility: hidden` which will hide the DIV and still allow the chart to generate properly. If you would like to completey mimic the `display:none` css, I used the following styles:

```
visibility: hidden;
position: absolute;
top: -9999px;
left: -9999px;
```

Hope this helps you.